# Use .replace() for multiple instances

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to replace all instances of `<br />` with `\u000A`

```
data.replace("<br/>","\u000A");
```

works fine, for the first `<br/>` instance. All following `<br/>` tags are not replaced.

I thought

```
data.replace(/,/g,"").replace("<br/>","\u000A");
```

would work but it doesn't.

How can I use .replace() in order to have it apply to multiple instances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do something like `data.replace(/<br\/>/g, "\u000A")`.  Chaining a method call onto the result of a global replace doesn't make the chained method global...

Comment: I thought I tried that, I guess I didn't. Thanks for your help Mark.